# How can i override a javascript method (given in description) to return me url?

Tags: javascript

I just want u to go on: [webtrends.com](https://webtrends.com/products/analytics/) in chrome browser.
There on the console if u type: `dcsMultiTrack`(dcsMultitrack is a method in webtrends.js),
u will get a method description in response as:

```
dcsMultiTrack
function dcsMultiTrack() {
        var args_in = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            args_in[i] = arguments[i];
        var o = {
            "argsa": args_in
        };
        Webtrends.multiTrack(o);
    }
```

And now if i call this method in console typing: `dcsMultiTrack();`, response i get is:

```
dcsMultiTrack();
undefined
GET https://statse.webtrendslive.com/dcsgs0dqv8bv0h8ud5z2yrxxv_5c4y/dcs.gif?&dcsdat=1345196848140&dcssip=webtrends.com&dcsuri=/products/analytics/&WT.tz=5&WT.bh=14&WT.ul=en-US&WT.cd=32&WT.sr=1920x1080&WT.jo=Yes&WT.ti=Unified%2520Digital%2520Analytics%2520%257C%2520Webtrends&WT.js=Yes&WT.jv=1.5&WT.ct=unknown&WT.bs=1920x522&WT.fv=11.3&WT.slv=Not%2520enabled&WT.le=ISO-8859-1&WT.tv=10.2.30&WT.dl=0&WT.ssl=1&WT.es=webtrends.com%252Fproducts%252Fanalytics%252F&WT.ce=2&WT.vt_f_tlv=1345189668&WT.vt_f_tlh=1345192944&WT.vt_f_s=1&WT.vtvs=1345196848137&WT.vtid=7260947478808151196&WT.co_f=7260947478808151196  webtrends.js:1210
GET https://statse.webtrendslive.com/dcswxkx6r100004rra9vt8h0n_9g3z/dcs.gif?&dcsdat=1345196848151&dcssip=webtrends.com&dcsuri=/products/analytics/&WT.tz=5&WT.bh=14&WT.ul=en-US&WT.cd=32&WT.sr=1920x1080&WT.jo=Yes&WT.ti=Unified%2520Digital%2520Analytics%2520%257C%2520Webtrends&WT.js=Yes&WT.jv=1.5&WT.ct=unknown&WT.bs=1920x522&WT.fv=11.3&WT.slv=Not%2520enabled&WT.le=ISO-8859-1&WT.tv=10.2.30&WT.dl=0&WT.ssl=1&WT.es=webtrends.com%252Fproducts%252Fanalytics%252F&WT.ce=2&WT.vt_f_tlh=1345196848&WT.vtvs=1345196848137&WT.vtid=7260947478808151196&WT.co_f=7260947478808151196
```

I want to somehow override this method or create a new method to give me an alert of one of the urls i got. How can i do this? Any help will be appreciated.

I  am attaching the screenshot of what i am doing.!

[image: see what i wanted to do]

Comment: You'll need to debug the code starting from that `Webtrends.multiTrack` call in order to find out which part of the code is making the requests.